# Track Active item in Test Explorer in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, test-explorer

Just like a file can track an active item in Solution Explorer. Is it possible to do the same on Test Explorer?

- A class file can point to a class in test explorer.
- A method can point to the test method in test explorer.